# How to run a function when the layout or resolution changes on Windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I created a bar graph using rectangles whose size is proportional to the border of the graph.  However when switch to a different layout such as snap view, only the border's size changes and not the length of the rectangle.  How do I detect when the layout or resolution changes and call a function to update the rectangle's length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably use just the basic VisualStateManager for changing layout when Snapped/FullScreenPortrait/FullScreenLandscape.

In case you need more advanced behavior, use this approach:
- add SizeChanged handler to your Page
- also name the root Grid/Panel element as x:Name="Root" in your app and make it stretch horizontally and vertically.
- in the SizeChanged event handler you can find the actual screen size by accessing the Root.ActualWidth and Root.ActualHeight. Here you can show/hide/change/resize anything you want.

Comment: Thanks. the SizeChanged event handler is what I need.

Answer (score 1):

This is an article on MSDN about this exact topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780612.aspx

There is also a recommended approach that Microsoft seems to lean towards, and that is using a Visual state to trigger different visual layout changes.

If you do  File->New Project and choose the Grid App application, they already have code (checkout the App.cs) for hooking in to the changes of screen sizes and firing different visual states.

I have done a blog post on the anatomy of this project type as well if you are interested: http://markmacumber.net/2012/08/anatomy-of-the-grid-app-template-in-vs2012-for-windows-8-c-xaml.html

Comment: Thank you. I end up using event handler since visual states require a constant size.  Also, thanks for the guideline and breakdown of grid template